# How to limit text in textarea in html in function of fontsize

Tags: css, textarea, font-size, font-family

i have a textarea in which users can put only a limited number of character. I have a font-size selector and a font-family selector associated whit it. This textarea is on a image and i have to limit text in a limited space. in which way i can limit textarea in function of that parameters ( size and family) ? i hope i used the right words to explain my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxlength` for limit the length of textarea. The following HTML support only 5 character:

```
<textarea id="txtarea" maxlength="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: if size is 48px textarea support always 5 char and textarea will be resized?